# How to standard scale a 3D matrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am working on a signal classification problem and would like to scale the dataset matrix first, but my data is in a 3D format (batch, length, channels).
I tried to use Scikit-learn Standard Scaler:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

But I've got this error message:

> Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2

I think one solution would be to split the matrix by each channel in multiples 2D matrices, scale them separately and then put back in 3D format, but I wonder if there is a better solution.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll have to fit and store a scaler for each channel

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scalers = {}
for i in range(X_train.shape[1]):
    scalers[i] = StandardScaler()
    X_train[:, i, :] = scalers[i].fit_transform(X_train[:, i, :]) 

for i in range(X_test.shape[1]):
    X_test[:, i, :] = scalers[i].transform(X_test[:, i, :])
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Shouldn't it be like this: `for i in range(X_train.shape[1]):`

Comment: No, I think it should be X_train[:, :, i] = scalers[i].fit_transform(X_train[:, :, i]). At least for me when my data is structured as (batch, samples, rows, columns)

Comment: Thank you. Does this work on pandas frame columns? I have over 291 columns, so how we can apply same thing on pandas frame please?

Answer (score 32):

With only 3 line of code...

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1, X_train.shape[-1])).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test.reshape(-1, X_test.shape[-1])).reshape(X_test.shape)
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to scale each feature differently, like [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) does, you can use this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


class NDStandardScaler(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._scaler = StandardScaler(copy=True, **kwargs)
        self._orig_shape = None

    def fit(self, X, **kwargs):
        X = np.array(X)
        # Save the original shape to reshape the flattened X later
        # back to its original shape
        if len(X.shape) > 1:
            self._orig_shape = X.shape[1:]
        X = self._flatten(X)
        self._scaler.fit(X, **kwargs)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, **kwargs):
        X = np.array(X)
        X = self._flatten(X)
        X = self._scaler.transform(X, **kwargs)
        X = self._reshape(X)
        return X

    def _flatten(self, X):
        # Reshape X to <= 2 dimensions
        if len(X.shape) > 2:
            n_dims = np.prod(self._orig_shape)
            X = X.reshape(-1, n_dims)
        return X

    def _reshape(self, X):
        # Reshape X back to it's original shape
        if len(X.shape) >= 2:
            X = X.reshape(-1, *self._orig_shape)
        return X
```

It simply flattens the features of the input before giving it to sklearn's `StandardScaler`. Then, it reshapes them back. The usage is the same as for the `StandardScaler`:

```
data = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[1, 5], [2, 9]]]
scaler = NDStandardScaler()
print(scaler.fit_transform(data))
```

prints

```
[[[-1. -1.]
  [ 0. -1.]]

 [[ 1.  1.]
  [ 0.  1.]]]
```

The arguments `with_mean` and `with_std` are directly passed to `StandardScaler` and thus work as expected. `copy=False` won't work, since the reshaping does not happen inplace. For 2-D inputs, the `NDStandardScaler` works like the `StandardScaler`:

```
data = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
scaler = NDStandardScaler()
scaler.fit(data)
print(scaler.transform(data))
print(scaler.transform([[2, 2]]))
```

prints

```
[[-1. -1.]
 [-1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
[[3. 3.]]
```

just like in the sklearn example for [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

Comment: I have 291 columns in pandas dataframe, so I am wondering how we can apply same thing on pandas data frame please?

Answer (score 10):

An elegant way of doing this is using class Inheritance as follows:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

class MinMaxScaler3D(MinMaxScaler):

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        x = np.reshape(X, newshape=(X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
        return np.reshape(super().fit_transform(x, y=y), newshape=X.shape)
```

Usage:

```py
scaler = MinMaxScaler3D()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: True! this is elegant, shortest, simplest.

Answer (score 1):

I used **Normalization** scheme for my spatio-temporal data having shape of (2500,512,642) --> (samples, timesteps, features/spatial-locations).
The following code can be used for **Normalization** and its inverse also.

```
def Normalize_data(data):
    scaled_data = []
    max_values  = []
    min_values  = []
    for N in range(data.shape[0]):
        temp = []
        t1   = []
        t2   = []
        for i in range(data.shape[1]):
            max_val = np.max(data[N,i])
            min_val = np.min(data[N,i])
            norm = (data[N,i] - min_val)/(max_val - min_val)
            temp.append(norm)
            t1.append(max_val)
            t2.append(min_val)

        scaled_data.append(temp)
        max_values.append(t1)
        min_values.append(t2)
    return (np.array(scaled_data), np.array(max_values), np.array(min_values))

def InverseNormalize_data(scaled_data, max_values, min_values):
    res_data = []
    for N in range(scaled_data.shape[0]):
        temp = []
        for i in range(scaled_data.shape[1]):
            max_val = max_values[N,i]
            min_val = min_values[N,i]
            #print(max_val)
            #print(min_val)
            orig = (scaled_data[N,i] * (max_val - min_val)) + min_val
            temp.append(orig)
        res_data.append(temp)
    return np.array(res_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s0, s1, s2 = y_train.shape[0], y_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[2]
y_train = y_train.reshape(s0 * s1, s2)
y_train = minMaxScaler.fit_transform(y_train)
y_train = y_train.reshape(s0, s1, s2)

s0, s1, s2 = y_test.shape[0], y_test.shape[1], y_test.shape[2]
y_test = y_test.reshape(s0 * s1, s2)
y_test = minMaxScaler.transform(y_test)
y_test = y_test.reshape(s0, s1, s2)
```

Just reshaped the data like so. For zero padded use similar:

```
s0, s1, s2 = x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]
x_train = x_train.reshape(s0 * s1, s2)
minMaxScaler.fit(x_train[0::s1])
x_train = minMaxScaler.transform(x_train)
x_train = x_train.reshape(s0, s1, s2)

s0, s1, s2 = x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], x_test.shape[2]
x_test = x_test.reshape(s0 * s1, s2)
x_test = minMaxScaler.transform(x_test)
x_test = x_test.reshape(s0, s1, s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class if you're dealing with pipelines

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin,BaseEstimator
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

class Scaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler()

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1))
        return self

    def transform(self,X):
        return self.scaler.transform(X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1)).reshape(X.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another simple way by without using for-loops and making functions or methods. I just flattened the given input array by "array.reshape(-1,1)" then fit inside minmaxscaler. Later, after transformation, convert it into its original shape.

For example I have implemented on cifar10 dataset from tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

(x3d_train, y3d_train), (x3d_test, y3d_test) =cifar10.load_data()

s0_train,s1_train,s2_train,s3_train=x3d_train.shape

s0_test,s1_test,s2_test,s3_test=x3d_test.shape


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler1 = MinMaxScaler()

scaler.fit(x3d_train.reshape(-1,1))
scaler1.fit(x3d_test.reshape(-1,1))

x3d_train_norm=scaler.transform(x3d_train.reshape(-1,1)).reshape(s0_train,s1_train,s2_train,s3_train)
x3d_test_norm=scaler1.transform(x3d_test.reshape(-1,1)).reshape(s0_test,s1_test,s2_test,s3_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jude TCHAYE's answer comes in really handy for pipelines. However, the data is not properly reshaped in their solution. Better follow Marco Cerliani's answer here, which gives:

```py
class StandardScaler3D(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    A class for feature-wise scaling of 3D data.

    This class temporarily reshapes 3D data to 2D ([samples * time-steps, features]) 
    and applies the StandardScaler from scikit-learn on the last dimension. After scaling, 
    it reshapes the data back to its original 3D shape.

    Parameters
    ----------
    copy : bool, default=True
        If False, try to avoid a copy and do inplace scaling instead. This is not guaranteed to 
        always work inplace; e.g. if the data is not a NumPy array or scipy.sparse CSR matrix, 
        a copy may still be returned.

    Methods
    -------
    fit(X, y=None)
        Compute the mean and std to be used for later scaling.
        
    transform(X)
        Perform standardization by centering and scaling
    
    fit_transform(X, y=None)
        Fit to data, then transform it.
        
    inverse_transform(X)
        Scale the data back to the original distribution. This method assumes that the scaler 
        has already been fitted. If not, it will raise a ValueError.
    """

    def __init__(self, copy=True):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy=copy)
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        if len(X.shape) != 3:
            raise ValueError("Input array should be a 3D array.")
        self.scaler.fit(X.reshape(-1, X.shape[-1]))
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not hasattr(self.scaler, "scale_"):
            raise ValueError("The scaler is not fitted yet.")
        X_transformed = self.scaler.transform(X.reshape(-1, X.shape[-1]))
        return X_transformed.reshape(X.shape)

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        self.fit(X)
        return self.transform(X)
    
    def inverse_transform(self, X):
        if not hasattr(self.scaler, "scale_"):
            raise ValueError("The scaler is not fitted yet.")
        X_inversed = self.scaler.inverse_transform(X.reshape(-1, X.shape[-1]))
        return X_inversed.reshape(X.shape)
```