# Using Standardscaler on 3D data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Im trying to scale a dataset with multiple features and time-series data using the scikit-learn standardscaler. At the moment I am creating a seperate scaler for every feature:

```
scale_feat1 = StandardScaler().fit(data[:,:,0])
scale_feat2 = StandardScaler().fit(data[:,:,1])
..
```

Is there a way to scale all features separately using one scaler? Also what is the easiest way to save a scaler for all features and apply it to a valdidation dataset?

Edit: Standardscaler only works on 2D Arrays, so the array would have to be flattened for scaling. In 2D Standardscaler creates a seperate mean and std-dev for every feature

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601298/10375049

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your data is shaped `[num_instances, num_time_steps, num_features]` what I would do is first reshape the data and then normalize the data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
num_instances, num_time_steps, num_features = train_data.shape
train_data = np.reshape(train_data, shape=(-1, num_features))
train_data = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
```

This will reshape the data in a format where each feature is one column and it will normalize each feature separately. Afterwards, you can just return the data in the same shape before training.

```
train_data = np.reshape(train_data, shape=(num_instances, num_time_steps, num_features))
```

When it comes to the using the scaler on the validation set, the `fit_transform` method computes the `mean` and `std` on the train set and stores them in the object. Then, when you want to normalize the validation set you can do:

```
num_instances, num_time_steps, num_features = val_data.shape
val_data = np.reshape(val_data, shape=(-1, num_features))
val_data = scaler.transform(val_data)
```

And afterwards reshape the data in the shape that you need for training.

```
val_data = np.reshape(val_data, shape=(num_instances, num_time_steps, num_features))
```

This should do the trick for you.

Update:

As per @Medomatto comment, in the later `numpy` versions the correct way to reshape would be:

```py
... = np.reshape(data, newshape=(...))
```

Comment: For more recent Numpy versions the argument shape= is no longer used and can lead to an error. Otherwise great answer. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot too.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help and I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you are doing it, it seems one could straightforwardly do

```
scale_feat = StandardScaler().fit(data[:,:,:])
```

to apply the scaling to all the features.

If you want the scaling to be applied on let's say first 5 features, you can do

```
scale_feat = StandardScaler().fit(data[:,:,0:5])
```

Comment: Would this use a separate scale for every feature? For example if feat1 is describing a position and feat2 is describing a velocity, would they be scaled on separate scales?

Comment: This is something you would have to check. To do so, just compare your `scale_feat1` and `scale_feat2` values with the values of `scale_feat` which I posted.

Comment: The scaler creates a separate mean and std-dev for every timestep, but does not accept 3D arrays

Comment: Hence i probably have to flatten the array for all timesteps and then create a standardscaler which is fit on the flattened array, then transform the flattened array and reshape it to 3D